# SciFi Book Find - Alien Precursor Attack Before a Large Scale Invasion (not in series)

Tags: story-identification, books, hard-sci-fi, alien-invasion

**Some overall details;**

A book *series* I listened to as audiobooks in 2019-2022. They were newish books so published in the range 2010-2022. It had somewhere around 3 - 4 books. There was never a large scale invasion, unless some new books came out. Very technical and focused on the normal world trying to prove, find, and kill / capture these 5-7(?) aliens.

These aliens had incredibly advanced technology, and I believe all or most of them were heavily genetically modified AND cyborgs as well. They were outfitted and sent by a far away planet to destabilize Earth by any means possible, this was actually a planet and not a galactic federation or anything like that.

The series has subsequent phases of trying to prove these aliens exist, trying to convince increasingly senior people (i.e. secretary of state, CIA head) to believe this threat, how to deal with the incoming enemy fleet, and tracking down these infiltrators.

As the series goes on, it becomes increasingly obvious that;

A. There is an alien threat killing important people and destabilizing regions.

B. Earth is not responding fast enough to the threat.

The general gist is that the infiltrators are on an honor-suicide mission, and as long as the humans don't fully turn their attention to the incoming threat, the incoming fleet will be successful.

**Some of the technology / story notes:**

- Genetically modified to be an unassuming human from whatever continent they were to attack (one was Indian, one was Chinese, etc.)
- "Sub-space tweeters"(?) Morse code like communicators that were the only way to talk FTL, I think using quantum entanglement. I think they has pocket versions that relayed to hidden satellites, that then used a more powerful version to send to fleet.
- Panel / pixel based armour that acted as very effective, multi-wavelength (i.e. infrared) camouflage, this was separated from their genetic modifications and more of a war tool.
- I'm pretty confident there were 6-7 factions of aliens relating to continents on the other planet, I remember that 1 was specifically a rich nomadic seafaring race and the others were resource and war hungry (this is important for spoilers).

**Spoiler-ish details: Don't read below if you find that interesting and don't know the book name**

- Pretty far into the series, you find out that the nomadic race actually sent a double agent AND tipped off the original characters to the threat. They didn't agree with stealing an entire planet and had some bad blood about the other factions doing the exact same thing to them (minus the interstellar travel).
- The final alien was caught only after it detonated a nuke in either Texas or Florida.
- I don't remember exactly what they did, but the killed almost all the fleet in an asteroid or missile strike that was made possible with technical information given by nomadic faction; as well as an inside strike and suicide attack by this same faction against the attack fleet. They never made it Earth, or more accurately they didn't survive (Newton's 3rd...).

I feel like this is a pretty good synopsis, and if you don't know the book - I'm sorry for ruining portions of it. It's a fantastic book / series.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you listen to these books and when do you think they might've been published?

Comment: Listened 2019-2022; Newer book, so published in the range 2010-2022. Listened as an audiobook.

Comment: Bears some resemblance to John Ringo's Legacy of the Aldenata series, but I am sure you would have remembered the Posleen from later books.

Comment: @Akhenaten I found the info interesting and didn't know the book's name, and as I'm a rebel,  I *still* read the spoilers - because I'm never likely to read that series.

Comment: @Akhenaten If one of the answers below successfully answers your question, please accept the answer.

Comment: @PeterM I remember it as a fantastic series, worth it to read post-spoilers. There also appears to be a fourth book.....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this is probably the [Fear series](https://www.goodreads.com/series/143599-the-fear-saga) by Stephen Moss. The books were published in 2014 so that fits the time you remember listening to the audiobooks.

[image: Fear]

> In eleven years time, a million members of an alien race will arrive at Earth. Years before they enter orbit, their approach will be announced by the flare of a thousand flames in the sky, their ships’ huge engines burning hard to slow them from the vast speeds needed to cross interstellar space.
>
> These foreboding lights will shine in our night sky like new stars, getting ever brighter until they outshine even the sun, casting ominous shadows and banishing the night until they suddenly blink out.
>
> Their technology is vastly superior to ours, and they know they cannot possibly lose the coming conflict. But they, like us, have found no answer to the destructive force of the atom, and they have no intention of facing the onslaught of our primitive nuclear arsenal, or the devastation it would wreak on the planet they crave.
>
> So they have flung out an advanced party in front of them, hidden within one of the countless asteroids randomly roaming the void.
>
> They do not want us, they want our planet. Their Agents are arriving.

I have the first book, [Fear the Sky](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/22171697-fear-the-sky), though I don't recall ever reading it. However  quick skim suggests it matches many of the points in your description. For example they have the communicators you describe:

> As Leong-Lam walked away, he left no marker, nor did he worry about the safety of the device. His subspace tweeter relay would be watched over night and day by a far more powerful guardian in orbit, ready to bring to bear a host of unpleasant defensive weapons if the buried relay were somehow discovered by an unfortunate field hand.

*Pei Leong-Lam* is the first alien agent to be infiltrated and he is placed in the Officer Training School in China:

> Finding the keys it sought, the computer deftly opened the locks to the People’s Liberation Army’s vast personnel database, and planted a record within. In an organization as leviathan as the million-strong Chinese army, no one could possibly notice the appearance of the somehow preapproved application of Pei Leong-Lam to enter Officer Training School.

Answer (score 8):

This sounds like the [*Fear Saga*](https://www.goodreads.com/series/143599-the-fear-saga) by Stephen Moss (*Fear the Sky  Fear the Survivors, Fear the Future*). They were published in 2014.

The infiltrators were androids rather than genetically modified, but used the thoughts and memories of real aliens, and had been sent in advance of the main fleet. One of them, John Smith, is indeed a rebel and supports the humans.

Initially they need to start preparing for the invasion, but secretly - if the infiltration team realise they are known, they are likely to wipe out any organised resistance. Once they are dealt with, the focus becomes more strongly one of rapid technological advance to be able to effectively fight the main fleet.

The aliens represent a number of nations, with an infiltrators from each. The last to survive is from the Royal family of her nation, and when caught she sets off explosives on two Ohio-class submarines, releasing the radioactive material in the warheads (so effectively a dirty bomb rather than a nuclear explosion). She does survive this, although is defeated in the second novel.

There is not a successful invasion, but the infiltrator storyline wraps up in the second book and the latter part of that one and all of the third relate to defeating the invasion fleet.